# how to make a recursive function that builds a list

Tags: python, list, recursion

What would be a good way to get a recursive function to build a list for return? Let's say I have a function like the following for generating a listing of files and directories at all subdirectories:

```
def print_directory_listing(directory = "."):                          
    for file_structure in os.listdir(directory):                
        file_structure_path = os.path.join(directory, file_structure)
        if os.path.isdir(file_structure_path):
            print_directory_listing(file_structure_path)
        else:
            print(file_structure_path)
```

Rather than printing out everything, how could I modify this to return a list of all of the files and directories? For example, would it be good to have a global list to which the function appends files?

Note that I am not asking for details on `os.walk`; I am asking a general question on what the Pythonic way would be to get a recursive function to build and return a list.

Comment: Why you don't use `os.walk()` which is exactly for this aim?

Comment: @Kasramvd Why don't you make an answer instead of a comment, since this is definitely an answer ?

Comment: @Loïc Because this question is duplicate.

Comment: @Kasramvd My question is *not* about creating a directory listing; it is about how to have get a recursive function to build a list and return that list. The fact that I mentioned directory listings is entirely incidental.

Comment: This is not a good example for demonstrating your task, you better to ask a question with providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As a hint you can also see the source of `os.walk()` function which uses a recursive approach https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py#L298

Comment: @Kasramvd How is this not a good minimal example? The full function is given, using simple code, doing a common task. Thanks for the link to the `os.walk` function; I'm trying to understand it now.

Could you turn off the "duplicate" status for this question? The "duplicate" you have suggested does not address the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to your comment I think having understood the real purpose of your question. If you take a look to the following code, you will find the recursion you are looking for and you will see how to "save the variables of the childs".

```
import os

def print_directory_listing(directory = '.'):
    files_list=[]

    for file_structure in os.listdir(directory):                
        file_structure_path = os.path.join(directory, file_structure)
        if os.path.isdir(file_structure_path):
            files_list+=print_directory_listing(file_structure_path)
        else:
            files_list.append(file_structure_path)

    return files_list
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. My question is not specifically about creating a directory listing; it is about how to have get a recursive function to build a list and return that list.

Comment: I have an example code for you, I cannot add an answer to the question. It is closed. Will you ask a new question?

Comment: @d3pd I just Updated my answer